# Get class labels from Keras functional model

Tags: python, keras

I have a functional model in Keras (Resnet50 from repo examples). I trained it with `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory` data and saved model to `.h5` file. When I call `model.predict` I get an array of class probabilities. But I want to associate them with class labels (in my case - folder names). How can I get them? I found that I could use `model.predict_classes` and `model.predict_proba`, but I don't have these functions in Functional model, only in Sequential.

Answer (score 89):

```
y_prob = model.predict(x) 
y_classes = y_prob.argmax(axis=-1)
```

As suggested [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5961).

Comment: This gives me the offset, but I already had a way to figure that out... how do I get the label name?

Comment: Keras sorts the labels (names of folders in the train directory) by alphabetical order. If  you have a list of labels called `labels`, the predicted label name will be: `predicted_label = sorted(labels)[y_classes]`

Comment: you can also call `model.predict_classes` to retrieve the highest probability class in a multi-class output vector

Comment: Hey @Guillaume could you please point me to the docs where this `alphabetical ordering` is mentioned? This is a very crucial info that I just don't seem to find anywhere. thanks

Comment: nm, found it in `directory_iterator.py` in `keras_preprocessing` with code as ,

`
classes = []
for subdir in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
      if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, subdir)):
          classes.append(subdir)
`

Answer (score 57):

When one uses flow_from_directory the problem is how to interpret the probability outputs. As in, how to map the probability outputs and the class labels as how flow_from_directory creates one-hot vectors is not known in prior.

We can get a dictionary that maps the class labels to the index of the prediction vector that we get as the output when we use

```
generator= train_datagen.flow_from_directory("train", batch_size=batch_size)
label_map = (generator.class_indices)
```

The label_map variable is a dictionary like this

```
{'class_14': 5, 'class_10': 1, 'class_11': 2, 'class_12': 3, 'class_13': 4, 'class_2': 6, 'class_3': 7, 'class_1': 0, 'class_6': 10, 'class_7': 11, 'class_4': 8, 'class_5': 9, 'class_8': 12, 'class_9': 13}
```

Then from this the relation can be derived between the probability scores and class names.

Basically, you can create this dictionary by this code.

```
from glob import glob
class_names = glob("*") # Reads all the folders in which images are present
class_names = sorted(class_names) # Sorting them
name_id_map = dict(zip(class_names, range(len(class_names))))
```

The variable name_id_map in the above code also contains the same dictionary as the one obtained from class_indices function of flow_from_directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my interpretation this answers the actual question - getting the class labels

Comment: I agree, I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: shouldnt we defined the dictionary the other way around? `dict(zip(range(len(class_names),class_names, )))` so that you can directly use the output of argmax as a key?

Answer (score 17):

UPDATE: This is no longer valid for newer Keras versions. Please use `argmax()` as in the answer from Emilia Apostolova.

The functional API models have just the `predict()` function which for classification would return the class probabilities. You can then select the most probable classes using the `probas_to_classes()` utility function. Example:

```
y_proba = model.predict(x)
y_classes = keras.np_utils.probas_to_classes(y_proba)
```

This is equivalent to `model.predict_classes(x)` on the Sequential model.

The reason for this is that the functional API support more general class of tasks where `predict_classes()` would not make sense.

More info: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2524

Comment: Currently, the code for np.utils.py (see https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/np_utils.py) doesn't have probas_to_classes method. Did they change this into some other function? Please help me.

Comment: I have the same issue as @noobalert mentioned, it doens't have the function.

Comment: use `y_classes = y_proba.argmax(axis=-1)` instead

Comment: AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute 'np_utils'

Comment: @Zach Why axis = -1 and not 1 ?

Comment: @BhabaniMohapatra: `-1` means last axis in general, `1` means last axis only for 2D array.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Emilia Apostolova answer to get the ground truth labels, from

```
generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory("train", batch_size=batch_size)
```

just call

```
y_true_labels = generator.classes
```

Comment: This doesn't  seem to give the label names which is what the OP is asking.

Comment: As I said, it's a complement to the @Emilia Apostolova 's answer, using this in addition to what she said, you can get the label names just using `map`. Particularly I used this to make the confusion matrix. Back in time when I posted this, I didn't have reputation to comment in her answer, because that I posted here.

Answer (score 4):

You must use the labels index you have, here what I do for text classification:

```
# data labels = [1, 2, 1...]
labels_index = { "website" : 0, "money" : 1 ....} 
# to feed model
label_categories = to_categorical(np.asarray(labels))
```

Then, for predictions:

```
texts = ["hello, rejoins moi sur skype", "bonjour comment ça va ?", "tu me donnes de l'argent"]

sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)

data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)

predictions = model.predict(data)

t = 0

for text in texts:
    i = 0
    print("Prediction for \"%s\": " % (text))
    for label in labels_index:
        print("\t%s ==> %f" % (label, predictions[t][i]))
        i = i + 1
    t = t + 1
```

This gives:

```
Prediction for "hello, rejoins moi sur skype": 
    website ==> 0.759483
    money ==> 0.037091
    under ==> 0.010587
    camsite ==> 0.114436
    email ==> 0.075975
    abuse ==> 0.002428
Prediction for "bonjour comment ça va ?": 
    website ==> 0.433079
    money ==> 0.084878
    under ==> 0.048375
    camsite ==> 0.036674
    email ==> 0.369197
    abuse ==> 0.027798
Prediction for "tu me donnes de l'argent": 
    website ==> 0.006223
    money ==> 0.095308
    under ==> 0.003586
    camsite ==> 0.003115
    email ==> 0.884112
    abuse ==> 0.007655
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to save a "list" of labels in keras model directly. This way the user who uses the model for predictions and does not have any other sources of information can perform the lookup himself. Here is a dummy example of how one can perform an "injection" of labels

```
# assume we get labels as list
labels = ["cat","dog","horse","tomato"]
# here we start building our model with input image 299x299 and one output layer
xx = Input(shape=(299,299,3))
flat = Flatten()(xx)
output = Dense(shape=(4))(flat)
# here we perform injection of labels
tf_labels = tf.constant([labels],dtype="string")
tf_labels = tf.tile(labels,[tf.shape(xx)[0],1])
output_labels = Lambda(lambda x: tf_labels,name="label_injection")(xx)
#and finaly creating a model
model=tf.keras.Model(xx,[output,output_labels])
```

When used for prediction, this model returns tensor of scores and tensot of string labels. Model like this can be saved to h5. In this case the file contains the labels. This model can also be exported to saved_model and used for serving in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

To map predicted classes and filenames using `ImageDataGenerator`, I use:

```
# Data generator and prediction
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        inputpath,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=False)
pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=len(test_generator), verbose=0)
# Get classes by max element in np (as a list)
classes = list(np.argmax(pred, axis=1))
# Get filenames (set shuffle=false in generator is important)
filenames = test_generator.filenames
```

I can loop over predicted classes and the associated filename using:

```
for f in zip(classes, filenames):
    ...
```

**Addendum:**

The path in which the images are located `inputpath` needs to have a subdirectory in which the images are actually stored. The reason is that the generator looks for subdirectories. The generator will give a feedback during prediction:

```
Found 283 images belonging to 1 classes.
```

The `1 classes` part refers to the *one* subdirectory (this comes from the generator and is unrelated to the actual prediction).

So when your `inputpath` is (for example) `C:/images/`, the actual images are located in `C:/images/temp/`.

Comment: Could I ask a question about this? I've asked the full question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71125533/imagedatagenerator-predict-class-why-are-the-predictions-not-correctly-convert but for this, is inputpath one directory with a mix of two-class test images, or is it a directory, with two sub-directories, one per class?

Comment: @Slowat_Kela: See my update

Comment: Thanks a mil. Thought that would help but when I run your code exactly as above, they're all assigned to one class. if I read in each image with image.load_img and img_to_array and predict, they go to different classes. will make it a new question, thanks.

Comment: The "one class" comes from the generator (which thinks "this must be one class since it is one subdir"). However, this part is only for data staging. The actual prediction follows after the generator step and will assign classes according to the model prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this magic on your data generator

```
y_true_labels = train_generator. class_indices
y_true_labels
```

it will print (cat , dogs on my case)

```
{'cat': 0, 'dog': 1}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```py
model.predict(x_test).argmax(axis=-1)
```

Comment: This gives the predicted class _index_ (an integer). Op is looking for the contents of the original class names array (an array of strings).