# Error: ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

i have a problem with my Keras model. Using Stop sing images dataset, my neural network should detect traffic stop sign on image. Here is my model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([

layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same',
              input_shape=[128, 128, 3]),
layers.MaxPool2D(),

layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'),
layers.MaxPool2D(),


layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'),
layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'),
layers.MaxPool2D(),

layers.Flatten(),
layers.Dense(6, activation='relu'),
layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),

])


model.compile(
loss='mse', 
optimizer='adam',
metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

My dataset is just 2 folders (train and valid) containing only images of stop signs.

Here is my data import:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY4lQ.jpg

And here is my model fitting:

```
history = model.fit(
ds_train,
validation_data=ds_valid,
epochs=50,
)
```

Finally, when I'm trying to fit my model an error shows up:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d_144/kernel:0', 'conv2d_144/bias:0', 'conv2d_145/kernel:0', 'conv2d_145/bias:0', 'conv2d_146/kernel:0', 'conv2d_146/bias:0', 'conv2d_147/kernel:0', 'conv2d_147/bias:0', 'dense_78/kernel:0', 'dense_78/bias:0', 'dense_79/kernel:0', 'dense_79/bias:0'].
```

Comment: Why did you set `label_mode` to `None` instead of `categorical`?

Comment: I thought i don't need label_mode to "detection" problem, as i said this program only needs to detect a part of an image (traffic stop sign). Also when i tried to use label_mode categorical, an error showed up "No images found".

Comment: What exactly are you predicting and where are the labels for images you have?

Comment: I want my program to detect Stop sign on image and then detect its coordinates (x,y) width and height. Should I put those images in another folder inside train and validation folders?

Comment: The first thing is if you want to predict bounding box your model output should output 4 values and another thing is you are using `image_dataset_from_directory` to load inputs (labels will not be loaded by it because this isn't a classification problem) so you need to provide labels in the `fit` function along with `ds_train`.

Comment: Can you please give me an example how can i provide labels in "fit" function?

Comment: You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41749398/using-keras-imagedatagenerator-in-a-regression-model).