# What are the differences between building a model with and without using Sequential() in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have 2 `build_model` functions as below:

```
def build_model01():
    X_input = Input(shape=(784,))
    Y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(X_input)
    model = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = Y, name='build_model')
    return model

def build_model02():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(input_dim=784,units=1,activation='sigmoid'))
    return model
```

What are the differences between `build_model01` and `build_model02`? Are they practically the same? Will the differences affect other layers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there is no difference between the models created using the functional API (i.e. `build_model01`) and the same model created as a Sequential model (i.e. `build_model02`). You can further confirm this by checking the `Sequential` class [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/1788a0a901efccfffcead3d64a5b8e5876998d32/keras/engine/sequential.py#L24); as you can see, it is a subclass of `Model` class. Of course, Keras functional API [gives you more flexibility](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) and it lets you create models with complex architectures (e.g. models with multiple inputs/outputs or multiple branches).

Comment: @H42 That's right. Since models created using functional API, unlike Sequential models, may have multiple outputs, each with different output configuration, [it does not make sense](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2524#issuecomment-218590463) to have `predict_classes` or `predict_proba` methods. As an alternative, you can use the solution suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45176824/2099607).