# multi category Image classification with keras

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, keras, deep-learning

Hello I am trying to build an image classifier using Keras and CNN

I already trained a model for Binary classification and it works really well.

I applied the same knowledge to build a Image classification using multiple categories(Which is failing miserably)
I have 5 classes I have created 5 folders inside jpeg dir and the directoy structure is as follows

C:\Users\jpeg

1.train

2.test

Inside train folder I have 5 subfolders each folder corresponding to a class

C:\Users\jpeg\train

1.Auth_Docs
 2.Certificates_Reports
 3.Document
 4.Title
 5.communication

and i placed appropriate images in each folder

Followed the exact same structure in test folder as well

source code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
%matplotlib inline
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
image_gen.flow_from_directory('C://Users/Jpeg/train')
image_gen.flow_from_directory('C://Users/jpeg/test')
image_shape = (150,150,3)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=(150,150,3), activation='relu',))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=(150,150,3), activation='relu',))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=(150,150,3), activation='relu',))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# 
model.add(Flatten())

#hidden layer number of neurons
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))

# Here we say randomly turn off 30% of neurons.
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

# Last layer(add number of layers based on number of categories)
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#Training the model
batch_size = 16

train_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory('C://Users/jpeg/train',
                                               target_size=image_shape[:2],
                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                               class_mode='categorical'
                                               )
#Found 2434 images belonging to 5 classes.

test_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory('C://Users/jpeg/test',
                                               target_size=image_shape[:2],
                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                               class_mode='categorical'
                                              )
#Found 60 images belonging to 5 classes.

train_image_gen.class_indices
#o/p
{'Auth_Docs': 0,
 'Certificates_Reports': 1,
 'Document': 2,
 'Title': 3,
 'communication': 4}

#Fitting the model
from PIL import Image 
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
results = model.fit_generator(train_image_gen,epochs=50,
                              steps_per_epoch=100,
                              validation_data=test_image_gen,
                             validation_steps=12)

#saving the model
model.save('Document_Classification.h5')
#results.accuracy for my model gives around 80% of accuracy
```

Now the issue with testing the model

```
from keras.models import load_model
new_model = load_model('Document_Classification.h5')
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
import os,sys
from PIL import Image 
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
for a,b,c in os.walk("C:/Users/jpeg/test/communication"):

   for i in c:
     doc_img = image.load_img(os.path.join(a,i), target_size=(150, 150)) 
     doc_img = image.img_to_array(doc_img)  
     doc_img = np.expand_dims(doc_img, axis=0)   
     doc_img = doc_img/255
     #print (a,i)

     prediction_prob = new_model.predict_classes(doc_img)
     print(prediction_prob )
```

only output I get is

[2]

[2]

[2]

[2]

no matter which folder i use to test the o/p is the same a i.e in above example i used the communication folder images and the o/p is 2

same o/p when i test images from Auth_Docs,Title etc.

I don not see anything wrong in my code as this code worked for binary classification. Please advise

Also, I want to find what is the associated label with the output I am getting.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things you could do to troubleshoot. The amount of samples really matters; you should know this. Well, if I thought I had enough samples I'd save the images from the generators to check if they are ok (flow_from_directory - save_to_dir argument).

https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Also, while you are trainning, you could check tensorboard using callbacks (if you are using tensorflow) to see how bad/good your learning is going. Have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqgTU7_cBnk&index=4&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfhTox0AjmQ6tvTgMBZBEXN). See that what matters the most is val_acc.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your inputs but model.predict_classes should yied the class label(some places it is mentioned that for more than 2 classes it returns a onehot encoded value) but i just get an array [2] i want to know what label value it is predicting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971293/get-class-labels-from-keras-functional-model