# Difference between predictions from ImageDataGenerator, and image.load_img predictions?

Tags: python, image, keras

I have a test directory with a sub-directory called all_classes, and in all_classes is a set of images belonging to one of two classes.

When I run code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971293/get-class-labels-from-keras-functional-model/57661560?noredirect=1#comment125734460_57661560):

```
# Data generator and prediction
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/content/drive/test/',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary',
        shuffle=False)
pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=len(test_generator), verbose=0)
# Get classes by max element in np (as a list)
classes = list(np.argmax(pred, axis=1))
# Get filenames (set shuffle=false in generator is important)
filenames = test_generator.filenames
```

when I print `classes`, the output is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
```

i.e. the whole array is 0s.

```
When I run this instead:
file_list = ['/content/drive/test/all_classes/' + i for i in os.listdir('/content/drive/test/all_classes/') if i.endswith('.JPEG')]
prediction_list = []
for i in file_list:
  test_image = image.load_img(i,target_size=(150,150))
  images = image.img_to_array(test_image)
  images /= 255.0
  images = np.expand_dims(images, axis=0)
  prediction = model.predict(images)
  if prediction < 0.5:
    prediction_list.append(0)
  else:
    prediction_list.append(1)
```

The output is a mixture of classes:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
```

Can anyone explain the discrepancy in the predictions generated by both?